# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer to say they accept/decline the nomination. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following their acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Nominating myself... bit of an odd move but doing so because I proposed the site and am eager to see it grow. I've also got a decent amount of moderation experience as I proposed and moderate the Salesforce StackExchange site and am a big fan of the SE network in general.

[image: profile for LaceySnr on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I would like to offer my support to this community.

I have been programming computers of all sizes since the 1970s, so can provide my memories of the things from days gone by.  Backed up by an atticful of old notes and manuals.  It would please me to see old machines kept running by people who are able to dedicate more time to their preservation than I am.

I have been a member of the wider StackExchange community for three years, and believe it has no parallel as a means of exchanging information.  I would be happy to help steer the Retrocomputing site to success within this great framework.

I missed most of the private beta of Retrocomputing as I was out of the country on holiday when it started taking a break from computers of all kinds for a couple of weeks.  So I come later to the party than some others.  That just means I have a little catching up to do.

Comment: You are the sort of person who should be moderator here. But first, ask and answer (even self-answer) lots and lots. For questions, make a list of everything that comes to mind, then find out or recall the answer, and release them slowly (a few per day, not all at once). You will get hundreds of reputation points that way, and can start on the review queues sooner.

Comment: agreed, I've seen some of your work on ELU, ELL, and SF and it's been noble.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for their supportive comments, both here and elsewhere.  I'll do what I can to steer the site to graduation.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 That's a very awkward way to consider it. Making a list of everything that comes to mind to get it answered isn't what Stack Exchange is about. It's about asking questions that reflect the real problems you're facing. From personal experience as a diamond mod and as a high rep user, such 'manufactured' questions tend to be poorer in quality. At this critical stage in your site's growth, having high quality questions is paramount.

Comment: @corsiKa I didn't say post *all* of it, sorry if that was implied.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Retrocomputing Profile]
[image: Retrocomputing Meta Profile]
[image: Network Profile]

#### Notes:

I am nominating myself because I think I would make a good moderator. I like helping out around the site, even without a diamond, and I'm not a moderator elsewhere so can dedicate more time to this site.

I have been interested in older, more open computer systems for a long time: before I found the internet cable, I spent my time reading the `autoexec.bat` on a Windows 98 SE, and in doing so taught myself enough DOS to write a `Hello, World!` program. Ever since then, I have wanted to know more about how these computers work, and share the knowledge that I have about them.

There is currently not enough information online about retro-computers: while researching for [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/206/278), I trawled through many sites and found some of the best information sources about hardware to be online shops selling replacement parts - and they just describe the items.

I am the first <s>[and so far only](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61)</s> Gold Badge owner on the site, having posted the site's [first Hot Network Question](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/463/278) and brought many new users to the site. The question is now in the top five Google search results for "why basic built in" and "basic many operating systems". More importantly, the second result for "basic retrocomputing" is the [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag page - a tag now used by at least three questions.

I believe quality is better than quantity: we will go further by having a small high-quality site than by having a large low-quality site. I am currently patrolling the site, looking for places I can help out, and finding more information for [my answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/544/278) to a [particularly tricky question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/206/278) that has apparently never been asked online before.

**UTC+0**: On weekdays I am active a little bit from 7 to 8 am, and most of 4 to 8 pm. On weekends I am largely active from 8 am to 9pm, but may be inactive for a few hours if I am out somewhere.
**UTC-7**: On weekdays I am active a little bit from midnight to 1 am, and most of 9 am to 1 pm. On weekends I am largely active from 1am to 2pm, but may be inactive for a few hours if I am out somewhere.