# Can we please review the pending edits in the suggested edit queue?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, review

I've edited a bunch of tag wikis and excepts since I've joined the site all of them are still sitting as "pending edits."  Can some high-rep users please go through the review queue and review these edits?  Can we change the rep requirement for the review queues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there aren't sufficient users to review the queues, as a Stack Exchange Community Manger, I usually pick up the slack. But as we near the appointment of the [pro tem Moderators](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site) for this site, I tend to get behind as I have to sort through what is an immediate need versus what is better left to the new mods. Apologies.